# Applying offset correctly in an Interrupted Time Series Analysis using segmented regression in GLM in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, offset, segmented-regression

I would like to apply an offset to allow for the population within segmented regression using GLM on count data in R and need to ensure that the formula I am using is correct. Adding offset in 2 different ways to the formula below seems to operate as expected but I just wanted to check if they are right.

```
model <- glm(outcome ~  1 + Intv + Time * (1 - Intv) + Time * (Intv) * offset(log(Pop_Total)),
             data = data,
             family = poisson)

model4 <- glm(outcome ~ 1 + Intv + Time * (1 - Intv) + Time *  (Intv),
              data = data,
              family = poisson,
              offset = log(Pop_Total))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have `Time * (1 - Intv) + Time *  (Intv)` in formula? It yields the same as `outcome ~ Time *  (Intv)`. Also, I guess you intend to have `... + offset(log(Pop_Total))` and not `... * offset(log(Pop_Total))`. Otherwise, I am not sure that `model` and `model4` gives the same. See the examples in `help("glm")`.